# Custom class for extracting data from the formcollection in a postback in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, postback, formcollection

I've been wondering about the possibility of generating a strongly-type object from the formcollection to extract data from it.

In other words, is it possible to generate a class depending on the keys in the formcollection object?

For example:
Say you have a checkbox with the key "ID3" and value "false".
And be able to write:

```
bool CheckBox = FormObj.ID3.GetValue();
```

I realise it's maybe not the most useful thing in the world, but still interesting.

I'm guessing it's down to a language limitation.

Any thoughts on this?

Edit:

Ok, so if I have a list (unknown length) and do a `foreach` in my view and get checkboxes, how would I bind them in my controller?

```
    <% foreach (var item in Model.AllAttributes)
   { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.CheckBox(item.AttributeID.ToString(), item.Chosen) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.AttributeTitle %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.Category.CategoryName %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

What do I put in my controller?

Comment: You shouldn't be working with the `FormCollection` - that's for kids. Use strongly typed models, view models, and model binding instead. It will make your ASP.NET MVC experience *much* better. :) Also, the concept of "postback" doesn't exist in MVC - a form post is a form post. There's no state other than what's sent from the client to the server, hence the term REST. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is done by the ModelBinder and the DefaultModelBinder class works with most .NET Framework types, including arrays and IList, ICollection, and IDictionary objects but if need be, you can create your own ModelBinder. Check out [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx) for more details.

Your controller action would be something like this

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int id = dinner.ID;
                ...
                ...
```

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post.
So if I would name my checkboxes '"ID" + item.ID' how would I extract the bool?

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your edit:.

You will have to have a following class :

```
Attribute
{
    bool AttributeID;
    string AttributeTitle;
    cat Category;

}
```

and in your Model (e.g. Dinner) . you would have an

```
IEnumerable<Attribute> AllAttributes;
```

and then in controller you can access it:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Dinner dinner)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 bool id = dinner.AllAttributes[0].AttributeID;
```